# Unable to implement interceptor for cancelling axios request in case of timeout

Tags: javascript, axios, interceptor

In my Nestjs app I am using making Axios calls. I am trying to attach token to every axios request and only if there is a timeout error I want it to cancel the token, log error and stop that request. Currently with this Code, the interceptor works fine but it executes the if (Axios.isCancel(error)) { } block everytime. 
Even if there is no timeout and I get a valid Response.
I don't want to cancel token if there is no timeout.

Currently for every request I get irrespective of timeout or not!:

`======Request canceled=== Cancel { message: 'Operation canceled due to timeout!' }`

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, CallHandler, HttpCode } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import Axios from 'axios';
import { request } from 'https';
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {

  intercept(context: any, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {

    const CancelToken = Axios.CancelToken;
    const source = CancelToken.source();

    const url:string = context.url? context.url: context.args[0].url;

    Axios.defaults.timeout = 2000;
    Axios.get(url, {
      cancelToken: source.token
    }).then( (res)=> {
      console.log(res,'');
    }, error => {
        throw new Axios.Cancel('Operation canceled due to timeout!');
    }
    ).catch( (error)=> {
       if (Axios.isCancel(error)) {
         console.log('=====================Request canceled=======', error);
       } else {
         // catchError(error => throwError(new Error('Service Timed out!')))
         console.log('--else part------------------------------------');
       }
     });
    return next.handle();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are always throwing a `Axios.Cancel` for any error during the request. Maybe you should check it inside the promise error handler, not in the catch block, like this:

```
Axios.get(url, {
  cancelToken: source.token
}).then( (res)=> {
  console.log(res,'');
}, (error) => {
  if (Axios.isCancel(error)) {
    throw new Axios.Cancel('Operation canceled due to timeout!');
  } else {
    console.log('IT IS NOT a timout error.');
  }       
}
).catch( (error)=> {
   console.log('Error during token cancelation');
});
```